# Using Polymorphism in extends Class

Tags: java

I have a following code bellow and i don't understand why the output of this code is: "high high". In my mind the output must be: "Low Out"

```
public class A{

  private String runNow(){
    return "High";
  }

  static class B extends A{
    public String runNow(){
      return "Low";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    A[] a=new B[]{new B(),new C()};
    for(A aa:a)
      System.out.print(aa.runNow()+" ");
  }

}

class C extends A.B{

  public String runNow(){
    return "Out";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private` methods cannot be overriden. The rules are described in the [Java Language Specification 8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance
>   method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - Either:
>
>   - m2 is **public, protected, or declared with default access** in the same
>       package as C, or
>   - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2),
>       such that m3 overrides m2.

When you declare a `runNow()` method in `B` and in `C`, you are simply creating a new method. Try to add `@Override` to them for kicks. You will get a compiler error

> The method runNow() of type A.B must override or implement a supertype
>   method

In your for loop

```
for(A aa:a)
    System.out.print(aa.runNow()+" ");
```

you are calling `runNow()` on variables declared as type `A` and since you are in the `A` class you have access to them. **There's no polymorphism involved here.**

Comment: but if runNow() from class A is private, how can i do "aa.runNow()" and call runNow() from class A, because if this is private i can't call this method, right ?

Comment: @user2776409 You can call a class' private method from within that class, `main()` is inside `A`, but you cannot override that method. Try putting your `main()` is `C`.

Comment: Ow, it's true, I forgot this detail. Thanks.

Comment: I have one more doubt: When i call "aa.runNow()" (in object B) the first place where compiler search is in class A ? Always start in superclass and will down even subclass ? I.E: I'm calling "aa.runNow()" so the compiler found a runNow() in Class A, but let's see if have another runNow() in subclass, don't have, so execute runNow() from class A. right ?

Comment: @user2776409 Kind of. Although the object is `B`, the declared type of the variable is `A` (`A aa`), so the `runNow()` method is the method in `A`. If the method was public and therefore inherited, you would see what you originally expected of `Low Out` because of polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Since `runNow()` method in class `A` is `private`, it's not overridden at all. So, the output is as expected.

Try adding `@Override` annotation over the method in class `B`, and you'll see a compiler error.